# Gaps in derivation of thermodynamic property equations

Tags: thermodynamics, integration

If $h=h(T, P)$.

Does $ dh = c_pdT + \left[v - T\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_P \right]dP \Rightarrow h_2 - h_1 = \int_{T_1}^{T_2} c_pdT + \int_{P_1}^{P_2}\left[v - T\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T} \right)_P\right]dP $ ?

If so, how?

I apologize for this, but I just haven't been able to find an appropiate justification for this operative behavior in any of the Calculus, Differential Equations and Thermodynamics books in my possession. I'm particularly bugged by the "integration of differentials" and how it, before me, seems to damage the symmetry of the first equation in the statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean How??  How is it derived or how is it applied..  You are missing a factor of T in the equations.

Comment: Oh you're right; it has been corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is a **line integral** in $(T,P)$-space:

$$L(C)=\int_{C}dh$$

where $C$ is some curve that starts at $(T_1,P_1)$ and ends at $(T_2,P_2)$. In the most general case, the result $L$ of this line integral can be dependent on the curve $C$ that is integrated over.

However, assuming that the function $h(T,P)$ is differentiable, this means that $dh$ is an [exact differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential). One of the nice properties of an exact differential is that the result of a line integral is **path-independent**: any curve that starts at $(T_1,P_1)$ and ends at $(T_2,P_2)$ will have the same line integral, and in particular, that result is merely the difference in $h$ between the start and end points:

$$L(C)=h(T_2,P_2)-h(T_1,P_1)\equiv h_2-h_1$$

So, given that it doesn't matter which path we take in $(T,P)$-space, it makes the most sense to choose an "easy" one: first move "horizontally" from $T_1$ to $T_2$ while keeping $P$ constant, then move "vertically" from $P_1$ to $P_2$ while keeping $T$ constant.

Line integrals along the coordinate axes are easy to write; for example, for a path $C_0$ along the $T$-axis, from $T_1$ to $T_2$ with $P$ being kept constant at $P_0$, the line integral is:

$$\int_{C_0} dh=\int_{T_1}^{T_2}\frac{\partial h}{\partial T}\bigg\vert_{P=P_0}dT$$

and similarly for an integral along the $P$-axis. So, in the end, the result of our line integral is the sum of the integral along the "horizontal" segment and the integral along the "vertical" segment:

$$\int_C dh=h_2-h_1=\int_{T_1}^{T_2}\frac{\partial h}{\partial T}\bigg\vert_{P=P_1} dT+\int_{P_1}^{P_2}\frac{\partial h}{\partial P}\bigg\vert_{T=T_2}dP$$

Comment: AWESOME!. This is what I badly needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Now, the specific trouble is how does one go from $a$ to $b$ in the statement, e.g. by integrating both sides with respect to what? Also, according to the books, a differential of a two-variable function is itself a four-variable function, say, $dh= dh(T, P, dT, dP)$, and I know it can be used to approximate a value $h_2$ from a value $h_1=h(T_1, P_1)$, but that is of no use since there is no explicit function of $h$; as some of you know it can't be measured and the goal is simply finding a way for computing changes in it.

But the fashion in which one gets to this last instance doesn't make much sense to my unexperienced head.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know how you would use this equation to get the change in enthalpy in going from T1, P1 to T2, P2?

Comment: Oh no, I was saying that I didn't know how to find the way for computing the changes. But now I do. Thank you too.

Comment: Oh yeah??  Suppose you knew that heat capacity, not at all pressures, but, as is typically the case, only in the ideal gas limit of low pressures.  How would you proceed then?